# can't get scroll magic to work in JSFIDDLE (part 1 of 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation, scrollmagic

I have a one page scrolling website that I'm working on. I am trying to implement ScrollMagic and pin the first section so that the remaining sections of the website scrolls over top of the pinned section. I tried to create a jsfiddle to show the issue, but I can't seem to get jsfiddle working (first time using fiddle so I may have something not linked up correctly. [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/icekomo/2h6zth7p/)`...`

After I get this working I have a follow up / new question in regards to scroll magic, but I think it would be helpful if I am able to show my problem in the fiddle.

Comment: http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: thanks but the question is more as to why it's not working in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include external ScrollMagic libraries:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js
```

I've added them to your jsFiddle and it looks like everything is working correctly now.

https://jsfiddle.net/fxf4b2cg/

Have fun coding!

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple that I over looked.